# C++ boost replace_all quote

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem with `boost::replace_all`. My string looks like:

> ""Date"":1481200838,""Message"":""

And I would like it to look like:

> "Date":1481200838,"Message":"

So i would like to replace `""` with single `"`:

```
boost::replace_all(request_json_str, """", """);
```

But it doesn't work at all. Same with:

```
boost::replace_all(request_json_str, "\"\"", "\"");
```

How could I make this to work?

Comment: `const auto msg = "\"Date\":1481200838,\"Message\":"s` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I would like to replace all occurence of double quote "" with single quote "

Comment: Ah, so you need a double quote following the second colon? `const auto msg = "\"Date\":1481200838,\"Message\":\""s` Or are you saying that you're being given a string that contains all those repeated quotes and you want to remove the leading quote in each case?

Comment: The second case

Comment: as @Zafi said.. it should as per your descrption.. see [live here](https://ideone.com/lggvTN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correctly escape the `"` character in your call to boost::replace_all!

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string msg("\"Date\"\":1481200838,\"\"Message\"\":\"");
  boost::replace_all(msg, "\"\"", "\"");
  std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run it?

Comment: The same input, the same output, to be more specific it's a json {""Event"":[{""ErrorCode"":10483,""Date"":1481202341,""Message"":""}]}

Comment: Is it some custom object or a stringified json? For a regular string my code should work...

Comment: At least show us the exact contents of request_json_str. Print it to std::cout and show us what it is!

Comment: Guys I am really sorry, I have logging into csv file (excel format) and it was formatted to this format when we call operator << every time I need to write something into logs.

Answer (score 1):

The `boost::replace_all(request_json_str, "\"\"", "\"")` already in your answer is the correct way to handle this using `boost::replace_all`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af7cbc753e16cf4f

I wanted to post an additional answer to say that given `auto request_json_str = "\"\"Date\"\":1481200838,\"\"Message\"\":\"\""s` the repeated quotations could also be removed without Boost (though not quite so eloquently, using [`unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), [`distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), and [`string::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize)):

```
request_json_str.resize(distance(begin(request_json_str), unique(begin(request_json_str), end(request_json_str), [](const auto& a, const auto& b){ return a == '"' && b == '"'; })));
```